# WhereNotIn not working in eager loading laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I Am using in Laravel 8 app next lines of codes, the problem is it is not filtering anything.

When I am using whereIn instead my app returns items as expected but when I add whereNotIn something goes wrong and not returning items opposite items to whereIn but all items.

```
$callback = function ($query) {
      $query->whereHas('documents', function($query) {
            $query->whereNotIn('document_type_id', $this->negative_documents);
      });
};
$companies = $companies->whereHas('people', $callback)->with('people', $callback);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try with `!` explanation mark like this:
`$query->whereIn('document_type_id', '!=', $this->negative_documents);`

Comment: You are grabbing companies which have people which have documents which don't have this list of `document_type_id`. I think your problem is that you are grabbing people who have documents. Even if the person has 1 document not in the list, it has a document, so the person will be loaded, so the company will be loaded. This is most likely true for all people so all companies, so all get loaded